# This keyword in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There's function

```
changeSong: function(index) {
    this.setState({currentSongIndex: index };
}
```

I need to run changeSong function passing index as argument by clicking on my div

```
var listTemp = data.map(function(item,index) {

        var listTemp = data.map(function(item,index) {

        return (
            <div key={index} className="eachTrack" onClick={this.changeSong({index})}>
                <span className="duration">{item.duration}</span>
                <a href="#" className="songTemplate" >{item.artist} - {item.track}</a>

            </div>  
        )
    }.bind(this))
```

It just runs my changeSong function 3 times(as much as I have div elements). Now it just running without even passing "index" argument, there's also no event by click.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to bind the desired context for the event handler? Moreover, the `changeSong` function is executed immediately upon render, so unless it itself returns a function this will also lead to problems. Simply wrap it in an arrow function.

Comment: I believe @oens is on the right track. Just noticed his comment after submitting an answer, but it might illustrate what he is referring to.

Answer (score 2):

You need to **bind** this:

```
var listTemp = data.map(function(item,index) {
  return (
            <div key={index} className="eachTrack" onClick={this.changeSong({index})}>
                <span className="duration">{item.duration}</span>
                <a href="#" className="songTemplate" >{item.artist} - {item.track}</a>

            </div>  
        )
    }.bind(this))
```

or pass **this** into the map function:

```
var listTemp = data.map(function(item,index) {
  return (
            <div key={index} className="eachTrack" onClick={this.changeSong({index})}>
                <span className="duration">{item.duration}</span>
                <a href="#" className="songTemplate" >{item.artist} - {item.track}</a>

            </div>  
        )
    }, this)
```

as others have noted, you might want to wrap the the changeSong function in an arrow function so that it isn't executed immediately on render:

```
<div key={index} className="eachTrack" onClick={() => this.changeSong(index)}>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! it's now almost working now)) When page is ready changeSong completing three times(as much as I have div elements), but when i'm clicking on it nothing happens. It's just console.log() function. What could I do wrong?

Comment: @congressor hmm thats a tough one to answer without seeing the rest of your code

Comment: Got it. It just runs my changeSong function 3 times, but i need it to run by click event with index argument, so it calls  changeSong: function(index) {this.setState({currentSongIndex: index } How could I do that?

Comment: @congressor do you think you can update your question above with the most recent issue and relevant code?

Comment: @congressor see update above regarding wrapping changeSong in an arrow function

Comment: thank you very much!! i really appreciate your help!

Comment: @congressor no problem! It was a group effort!

Answer (score 1):

You should bind context for `this` using `.bind(...)` or by supplying the context argument to `.map(...)`. Also make sure you supply a proper function as your event handler. In particular, wrap your handler in an arrow function to properly pass `index` upon event dispatch,

```
<div key={index} className="eachTrack" onClick={() => this.changeSong(index)}>
```

Comment: thank you very much!! i really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

When using plain ES5 Javascript you need to explicitly bind `this` to a function.  Fortunately, `Array.prototype.map` takes a second argument for the `this` context.

```
var listTemp = data.map(function(item,index) {

        return (
            <div key={index} className="eachTrack" onClick={this.changeSong({index})}>
                <span className="duration">{item.duration}</span>
                <a href="#" className="songTemplate" >{item.artist} - {item.track}</a>

            </div>  
        )
    }, this); // Passes in the parent `this` context to the map callback function
```

Comment: much better description and example than my answer!

Comment: Or you can use arrow function which has no context... arr.map( (item, index) => {...})

Comment: thank you very much!! i really appreciate your help!